# Where can I find legal or business resources for a game production company?

Tags: books, legal, business

Where can I find information on the legal or business aspects of running a game production company?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for resources, which we do not support.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, I'm making the Answer a *wiki* - feel free to update this post rather than start new answers.

- **Books**
  [Business and Legal Primer for Game Development](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584504927)
  [Secrets of the Game Business](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584503998)
  [Indie Game Development Survival Guide](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584502142)
- **Websites**
  [Tom Buscaglia: The Game Attorney](http://gameattorney.com/blog/)
  [Game Company Legal Kits](http://www.gamedevkit.com/index.html) - sold by same author above, different site.
- **Web PDF**
  [MASTERING THE GAME](http://www.wipo.int/edocs/pubdocs/en/copyright/959/wipo_pub_959.pdf)

And the usual disclaimer: [Caveat Emptor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caveat_emptor)