# Legal and IP considerations with publishers and playable prototypes

Tags: legal, mobile, publishing, intellectual-property

I'm almost ready to send a playable prototype of a game to a publisher.  I've never worked with publishers.  What legal or intellectual property issues should I consider at this stage (if any)?

In this specific case the publisher is well known... perhaps this makes a difference.  Also the game is for a mobile platform.

Comment: Mostly, you should consider hiring a lawyer. Also, IANAL. But if you believe your IP is important enough, consider formally filing for Trademarks and Copyrights where appropriate.

Comment: I have to say go with the comment above and get a lawyer.. make your demo include some sort of NDA at the very least if you feel your prototype is of that level. What I would add though is that all the big name publishers that I know (Activision Blizzard, EA, etc) reject game concepts/prototypes from the public out of hand. It might be a bit different in the mobile market but unless you have a contact at the company and there is interest and paper work going back and forth, you may just be wasting your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out some of the books in the answer to [Legal Resources?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/280/where-can-i-find-legal-or-business-resources-for-a-game-production-company), specifically [Business and Legal Primer for Game Development](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584504927).